# Ajax request to Laravel 4 returns 200 ok but method always return fail

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-4

IM doing i simple request to a Laravel web service.

This is the response in the controller:

```
data = array(
 'name' => 'Dummy',
 'size' => 'XL',
 'color' => 'Blue'
 );
 return Response::json($data);
```

Using POSTman i can see that everything looks fine:
URL:

```
Response:
{"name":"Dummy","size":"XL","color":"Blue"}

HEADERS:
Cache-Control →no-cache
Connection →Keep-Alive
Content-Type →application/json
Date →Mon, 04 Nov 2013 15:15:27 GMT
Keep-Alive →timeout=5, max=100
Server →Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.3-1ubuntu2
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
X-Powered-By →PHP/5.5.3-1ubuntu2
```

Then i go to a simple javascript call, like:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/myapi/public/content", function(json) {
                console.log("log " + json.name);            
            });
```

or

```
$.ajax({ 
type: 'get', 
url: 'http://localhost/myapi/public/content',
 dataType: 'json', 
async: false, 
success: function(data) { alert("success"); }, 
error: function() { alert("error"); } });
```

Firefox console returns a "200 OK", but Javascript always report an error.

where is the problem??

SOLUTION:

Laravel Response is not sending by default

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Just added and now im getting the json data correctly.

Comment: Is the hostname a different hostname? It could be a CORS security type issue.

Comment: you have an invalid JSON output. that's why the mehod is failing even with 200 OK status.

Comment: Hi, The JSON output seems valid (tested on JSONlint) and i cant catch any error code debugging with chrome or firefox. Im doing all the stuff on localhost.

Comment: The only error i got is that after calling the url, it triggers the error function.

Comment: What's the URL in your browser that is working? Does that work without index.php in the URL by coincidence or did you set up your mod_rewrite preferences to work like that?

Comment: The weird thing is im not getting any cors error on the javascript console. TRy to debug, but i dont get any error. i added the header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); and now is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to add an `App::after` middleware, in app/filters.php

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // You may also require these additional method calls
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '1000');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Origin, X-Csrftoken, Content-Type, Accept');

    return $response;
});
```